# how to add image.ico file in CustomTaskPanes

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

```
    {
       
        myUserControl1 = new UserControl1();
        myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "AmpliFund Addon");
        myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [CustomTaskPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane?view=vsto-2017) interface doesn't provide any property or method for setting an icon. But you can place any icon on the pane itself by using the [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image?view=net-5.0) class which represents a control that displays an image. The Image class enables you to load the following image types: .bmp, .gif, .ico, .jpg, .png, .wdp, and .tiff.